# How to use pyinstaller on debian?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, debian, pyinstaller, pipx

I have installed pyinstaller by pipx, but I still can not use it.

```
pyinstaller -F -n justRunMe test.py
-bash: pyinstaller: command not found
```

Or is there any other way to install pyinstaller? btw, I can't use pip to install :(